# How to avoid opening new tab in Lighthouse through CLI?

Tags: angular, performance, performance-testing, lighthouse

I want to run lighthouse to analyze performance of my web app built using angular and asp.net core. When I test on production, I get accurate results but when I test it locally I always get low performance. For example, below is the absurd result when I run it on localhost:

[image: img]

So, I decided to run it though command prompt using `lighthouse http://localhost:4200` but it opens a new tab. The problem is I am having Azure AD Authentication and can't enter credentials once the test has begun.

So, is there a way to run the test in the existing browser tab where I am already logged in using CLI?